# Laravel 5.2 - assign class to option in select box

Tags: forms, laravel

how one can assign class="some_class" to option in select box?

i would like to have

```
<select class="my_class" name="example">
<option selected="selected" value="">Choose something ...</option>
<option value="1" class="some_class">Hello</option>
<option value="2" class="some_class">World</option>
</select>
```

But I don't have any idea how to do it.. my form looks like:

```
{{ Form::select('example', array('1' => 'Hello', '2' => 'World'), null, array('class' => 'my_class', 'placeholder' => 'Choose position ...')) }}
```

How can I add "some_class" attribute to OPTION menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form builder doesn't support class attributes for `option` tags. You will either need to build the `select` manually, or use JavaScript / jQuery to add the class to the `option` tags.

Comment: merde :( thx for reply.. problem is, I'd like to assign different class per "category" of this ... maybe i will try to look for ajax solution or rebuild the logic of my select ... cause I really would like to use Form builder (i don't want to handle errors and other events manually)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `my_class` similar to this:

```
.my_class select option{
    font-size: 20pt;
    color:red;
}
```

This will affect only `<option>` elements of your `<select>` element.

Also, you can use JS to do this.

Comment: i asked how to assign class to option directly in laravel .. i know how to define class in CSS :)

Comment: Well, it's not possible. But why did you choose answer without any solution?

Comment: Solution is: It is not possible :)